# angular curly braces inside dom attribute

Tags: html, angularjs, dom, curly-braces

I'm trying to do an html import with angular to link to a dynamic page.

```
//SampleController
$scope.id = 1;
//sample.html
<p>{{id}}</p> <!-- 1 -->
<link rel="import" href="/samples/{{id}}">
```

The `<p>` tag shows the id however the href attribute gives the error...

```
cannot GET /samples/%7B%7Bid%7D%7D 404
```

It seems that the curly braces are not expanding inside the href attribute. Can I do something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ng-href`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)

> Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in an href attribute will make the
>   link go to the wrong URL if the user clicks it before Angular has a
>   chance to replace the {{hash}} markup with its value. Until Angular
>   replaces the markup the link will be broken and will most likely
>   return a 404 error. The ngHref directive solves this problem.

```
<link rel="import" ng-href="/samples/{{id}}">
```